# Delta Method and Asymptotic Variance

Tags: self-study, delta-method

I am working through a statistics course right now and struggling a lot with this question. I'm not really sure where to begin.

[image]

Any reading or idea where I should begin? I really need to understand this and I just dont.

Comment: This is often known as a [variance-stabilizing transformation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=variance+stabilizing+transformation).  The link goes to a search that points to dozens of worked examples.  When "Poisson" is also included as a search term, the top hit is at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192377.  Also including "delta" produces [this nice answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/10661/919).

Answer (score 0):

The square root transform is the so called "variance stabilizing" transform of a Poisson distributed random variable.

The Delta Method states:

[image: Source:Wikipedia Delta Method]

So you can easily derive the square-root function of the parameter, square it, and multiply the result by the known variance of a Poisson distributed random variable to obtain a constant variance.